# PHP XPath - breaking HTML content into nodes (include empty nodes)

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath, domdocument

I'm trying to break the HTML string into individual nodes with their text content (or not if empty).

This is the HTML string that I have:

```
<p>Paragraph one.</p>
<p><strong>Paragraph <em>two</em></strong>.</p>
<p>Some <strong>other paragraph</strong> three.</p>
<p>Last paragraph - paragraph four.</p>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Table paragraph one</td>
            <td>Table paragraph two</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Table paragraph four</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The code that I have at the moment almost achieves what I want:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML('<div class="root">'.$content.'</div>');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$nodes = $xpath->evaluate('//text()');

foreach($nodes as $node) {

    echo $node->getNodePath();
    echo '<br>';
    echo $node->textContent;
    echo '<hr>';
}
```

But it won't include empty nodes, like this one table cell (results below - tr[2]/td[1] is not on the list). How can I force it to include empty nodes without any #text in them as well, and without creating duplicates?

Current results:

```
/div/p[1]/text()
Paragraph one.

/div/p[2]/strong/text()
Paragraph

/div/p[2]/strong/em/text()
two

/div/p[2]/text()
.

/div/p[3]/text()[1]
Some

/div/p[3]/strong/text()
other paragraph

/div/p[3]/text()[2]
three.

/div/p[4]/text()
Last paragraph - paragraph four.

/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/text()
Table paragraph one

/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/text()
Table paragraph two

/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/text()
Table paragraph four
```

As you can see, the empty nodes are not included. How do I include them? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This version of `$nodes` should get you close enough, though not exactly to, your expected output:

```
$nodes =$xpath->evaluate("//text() | //*[not(text())]");
```